# How to convert sound energy to dc voltage?

Tags: microphone

I am ee student at METU and i have a project that is about vehicle moving depending to notes of flute. In first step,i need to convert notes of flute to dc voltage. I guess i need a basic microphone for this purpose but how can i use it ?

Comment: You will first need a DSP to analyse the sound so that your system can detect different notes.

Comment: Exactly how many notes do you need to interpret and what kinds of actions (and how many) can they cause? The universal answer will be what's called "signal processing." But that's a big field with a lot of sub-specialties in it (like beam-forming, for example.) So writing out, in detail, what you need to do is probably going to be important if you want to keep this project manageable. (I'm assuming this is a 3rd or 4th year project.)

Comment: some info on  flute harmonics  http://www.musiccrashcourses.com/lessons/harmonic_series.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is a two-note system

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEinEP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The upper output (top right) will switch Low at about 1,600 cycles/second, or G  note 2.5 octaves above middle C. The lower output will switch Low at about 3 octaves above middle C. Adjust values of R12 and R13 for tolerance to tuning of the flute.

C2/L1 set one tone. C1/L2 set other tone.

Answer (score 0):

Acoustic energy is not just frequency or voltage either. Is the voltage of a flat pressure transducer ( i.e. high quality flat response $$$ microphone) and square root of spectral density squared (RMS) or the calibrated heat energy produced into a load resistor received from path loss from a 1 watt "emitter" at 1 meter.

Look up B&K *(Brüel & Kjær is the world's leading supplier of advanced technology for measuring and managing the quality of sound and vibration.)* and see their $50k instruments.  But there are tools on Windows (Audacity) or an iPhone that give a relative  spectral density of cheap microphones that would need to be calibrated in an anechoic studio or get the specs online.

[image]